# Each row in my drop down is made up of 3 variables, how do I reference and pass them to form 2?

Tags: php, html, arrays

In my drop down list, each row has 3 fields from a db. I somehow need to pass these to another form where I will reference them in another SQL statement.

I'm not sure how to pass them. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
<form action='obtainaprice.php' method='POST'>
<?php

echo "<select name='makes' id='searchtext'>\n";

    $query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT make, type, model FROM device ORDER BY make, type, model";

    $result1 = mysql_query($query1)
       or die ("Couldn't execute query.");

    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
         $i=0;
             echo "<option value= \"" . $i . "\">" . $row1['make'] . " " . $row1['type'] . " " . $row1['model'] . "</option>";

             $i++;
    }

    echo "</select>\n";
?>
<input type="image" id="buttons" alt="Search" img src="images/button.png">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you would make the value of the options the row's id, which you need to select:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT id, make, type, model FROM device ORDER BY make, type, model"
```

assuming your primary index is called id...

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

Then on your next page you would run the next query based on the post value for makes...

```
 "SELECT id, make, type, model FROM device WHERE id = ".$_POST['makes']
```

of course, you need to sanitize this. You should switch to mysqli or PDO.

Side note - you should break out of php for writing html. It's just cleaner. Run your query first so you don't die in the middle of a select box. I don't condone use of mysql_ functions but for the sake of example here is what I mean...

```
<?php
    $query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT id, make, type, model FROM device ORDER BY make, type, model";
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1)
       or die ("Couldn't execute query.");
?>
<form action='obtainaprice.php' method='POST'>
    <select name='makes' id='searchtext'>
    <?php while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row1['make']; ?> <?php echo $row1['type']; ?> <?php echo $row1['model']; ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="image" id="buttons" alt="Search" img src="images/button.png">
</form>
```

Comment: This is great Kai, exactly what I need. As a side note, love the website. Do you make money from it?

Comment: ha... yes, strangely I do. But everything is hand made, so it's a hobby that turns out being a little more work than anticipated. Started as a joke. Who knew?

Comment: Also, if this answer was what you needed, mark it as accepted. It will help boost your rating and help anyone else that may happen to have this exact, yet very specific, problem.

Comment: Kai, is it just a case of clicking on 'Was this post useful to you?' or do you do this else where? (embarassing)

Comment: there should be a check mark under the big zero to the left of my answer. If not, it will tell you how long you have to wait to mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your option element can only pass back 1 thing (a string), so you'd have to parse it first to get the make, type and model back out of it before running the next SQL statement.

Why don't you have 3 select elements? 1 for each of make, type, model.

What is the next SQL statement you want to use the values in?

Comment: I was trying to have it as neat as possible. The next select is a price based select based on the previous. Cheers Bolkin